# creating dual box-shadow effect (like two spotlights)

Tags: javascript, css, box-shadow

I would like to create a dual box-shadow effect, like two spotlights on a page.

Code and fiddle:

```
<style>
.greenbox1{
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#00aa00;
  float:left;
}
.greenbox2{
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align:center;
  margin-right: 100px;
  background-color:#00aa00;
  float:right;
}

.spotlightme{
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0, 0, 0,.4);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
  border-radius:10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
</style>
<div class="greenbox greenbox1">
  <span class="spotlightme">spotlight</span>
</div>
<div class="greenbox greenbox2">
  <span class="spotlightme">spotlight</span>
</div>
```

In this jsfiddle, both are too shadowy: https://jsfiddle.net/7htp62h1/6/

And in this one, only one has a correct spotlight:
https://jsfiddle.net/7htp62h1/8/

I'd like there to be a light on both words "spotlight" and similar shadowing on the rest of the page.

As a bonus, I'd love to know how to make these spotlight effects 'fade in'.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Not sure I understood your question.
But I've played a bit with your* [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/7htp62h1/9/).

Any how, 
**this is how `box-shadow` works:**

`box-shadow: inset x-axis y-axis fade-out grow color`

- `inset`: inverts shadow's logic, growing into the element instead of out of the element.
- `x-axis`: distance shadow will translate horizontally.
- `y-axis`: distance shadow will translate vertically.
- `fade-out`: distance it will take for the shadow's color to become fully transparent.
- `grow`: box-shadow starts with the same size as the box, given value increases initial size in all directions.
- `color`: can take in color name, hexcode, rgb, hsl, hsla or even better rgba *(red, green, blue, alpha)*.
- `inset, fade-out, fade-out & grow` **are optional.**

You can add **multiple shadows** to the same element and separate them with a **comma**.

*As you can see in the following code snippet.*

```css
.box {
  background-color: #888;
  margin: 20vh 40vw;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 25vh;
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,255,0.5), -20px 20px 10px 0 rgba(255,0,0,0.5), inset 0 -10px 30px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}

.black {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="black">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. I was hoping to have the whole page equally darker and just two spotlights. In this version, the immediate area around the word 'spotlight' darkens but not the whole page.